# Creating an OPC Server C#

Tags: c#, server, iot, opc

I'm trying to dig up information on creating an OPC server to connect a piece of software to an OPC network.

Essentially my customer has hardware connected to an aggregation software, we gather aggregate data from that software's SDK and now the challenge is to make that available to OPC.

There seems to be lots of options all of which are poorly documented online unless you pay to get into their eco systems or they are focused on you buying their specific server implementations. I am happy to pay for a licence but I'm trying to work out what I'm getting into.

I've checked out:

https://opcfoundation.org/ (seems my company needs to be a member to use the examples)

https://www.matrikonopc.com/ (seems the generic server toolkit is EOL)

http://www.opcconnect.com/freesrv.php (looked through the options there which range from pay to even investigate to ancient or poor quality open source)

Are there free options to explore the possibilities and effort involved in coding up a server?

What are the best paid (or free) options to get the job done quickly?

Should we just bite the bullet and buy into an eco system?

Comment: Can someone give me a hint as to why  this is downvoted? I'm green to OPC and happy to improve my question with some input. Thanks

Comment: You're just saying "What am I missing?" without stating what you're wanting from us. You're wanting us to recommend a product for you?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, have updated with a few questions. Agree I had left it too vague.

Comment: None of the questions you've asked are allowed on this site. Please review what's [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Great, I'd rather just delete the question at this point as clearly I'm not at the point of asking specific coding questions but obviously can't now. Stuck with a question gaining negative votes and no where to go..

Comment: Try deleting now.

Comment: I see the upvote has been removed but I'm still being told I can't delete as people have answered. Thanks for trying to help though.

Comment: It's not that the upvote has been  removed...it's that it has been countered with a downvote. If there is another downvote on the answer, then I think the question can be deleted (since the only answer will have a net negative score), and you'll both receive back the lost reputation from the downvotes.

Answer (score 0):

Your are right, to use Foundation libraries for commercial use the company must be a member and pay an annual fee.

Take a look to https://www.unified-automation.com/ they have online documentation about their OPC SDKs, and I believe they have demo versions

Another free option but written in Ansi C is open62541.org

... and I agree with you about downvoters, at least they should explain why they do it.

Comment: When a question is clearly off-topic, you should not answer it.